# SQL result in a different order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql command that is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tattoos` 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 176 ,5
```

I want to order the result asc.

So at first i get

```
176 177 178 179 180
```

But I want it to be

```
180 179 178 176 175
```

i dont want all the result to be in a different order so

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tattoos` 
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 176 ,5
```

will not work because i will get other results from the query.

I already tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tattoos` 
ORDER BY id DESC, id asc
LIMIT 176 , 8
```

but that wont change my results.

Comment: Keep track of the offset and apply a filter, e.g. `WHERE id > 175 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5`?

Comment: @eggyal no i wont get the results if a value wil be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * 
 FROM  `tattoos` 
 ORDER BY id ASC
 LIMIT 176 ,5
) AS t
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: i get #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @SvenB Try add the alias `AS t`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * 
   FROM  `tattoos` 
   LIMIT 176 ,5
   ORDER BY id
) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```